# Производительность рабочих процессов в SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint

Добрый день.
Есть SharePoint 2016 внутри которого крутится определенный бизнес-процесс со своей логикой.
Бизнес процесс реализован на базе рабочего процесса SharePoint. Не вдаваясь в логику скажу, что пользователь кликнув по ссылке в письме попадает на форму заполнения с кнопкой "Согласовать". Нажав на которую запускаются задачи и пр. вещи.

Проблема в том, что первый экземпляр рабочего процесса запускается достаточно медленно, в течении 30-40 секунд. А все последующие стартуют почти мгновенно.

Это напрягает руководство, которое приходит раньше всех и запускает этот процесс.

Все последующие процессы в течени всего дня запускаются быстро. Те же самые.
Складывается впечатление, что при первом запуске, SharePoint что-то поднимает с диска, загружает в память а потом уже работает только с памятью.

Можно ли как-то заранее подготовить шарик к старту рабочего процесса?
Перезапустить службу может или запустить системный джоб?

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что проблема в том, что IIS выгружает пул.
Варианты:

1. Увеличить время выгрузки пула
2. Периодически "[прогревать](https://serverfault.com/questions/373548/warming-up-an-iis-application-pool-automatically)" пул